# How do I add a new user in a ScrewTurn wiki?

Tags: screwturn

We have an internal development wiki setup that uses ScrewTurn, but I am struggling with the most basic of tasks which is to add new users or edit existing ones. This was setup by a former colleague that is no longer employed at the company and no one has any experience of the administration side of it.

Based on the [information available](http://www.screwturn.eu/Help.AdminUsers.ashx) this should be a very simple task, however the "Accounts" tab described and pictured in the previous link simply does not exist in the administration section of our wiki.

The tabs we have are Admin Home, User Groups, Wiki Pages, Categories, Snippets/Templates, Nav. Paths, Content Editing, System Log, Providers and Configuration.

We have 8 registered users, all set as administrators (confirmed in the front end and databased) and these are set granted as having full control.

So what am I missing? Can the "Accounts" section be hidden? Are we using a different version (the listed version is 3.0.5.600 which reports itself to be up to date)?

It looks simple enough to setup users in the database, but I'd like to be able to use the front end.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm particularly interested to know if you manually set up users via the database.

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis No sorry I haven't given any time to resolving this yet

Comment: I've been able to replicate this issue. The logged-in user may be an administrator, but has not been granted access to "User Groups" and "Accounts". We'd need another administrator to grant access to those two tabs (making them visible), or find another work around. I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select Administrators under User Groups and grant full control to your admins and uncheck unwanted restrictions under "Deny".

If you are cannot access the User Groups tab, try to login as super administrator to verify the permissions of your Administrators group.

To login as super administrator, add this to your web.config under `<appSettings>`:

```
<add key="MasterPassword" value="YourSecretPasswordHere" />
```

Then login with the user **admin** and the password you set.

And make sure to remove that setting after you sort things out.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about the 'admin' user.  Hopefully it will get rrrr out of a jam!

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll see if I can get someone to look into this soon. We've moved offices recently and the wiki hasn't been setup on the servers in the new domain. Once we get it running, I'll accept if this works.

Answer (score 2):

The admin menu was probably modified.  Try going directly to the page AdminUsers.aspx (so something like "http://yourwikidomain.com/AdminUsers.aspx").

To fix the menu, download the Screwturn install files from the web site (http://www.screwturn.eu/Download.ashx) and copy the "Admin.master" page to your site.  You may want to compare them first to see what changes were made.

Comment: Doug - I was able to replicate the issue without modifying Admin.Master. If the user is NOT a member of the Administrators group, and does not have explicit permission to "Manage User Accounts" and "Manage User Groups" those tabs will not appear for Administration.

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis - Interesting.  In looking at this again, it does make sense since the 'Administrators' is just a group with rights and not a defacto 'superuser'.  I think bubbassauro's suggestion should help rrrr if rights are the problem.